# Why does my operator== have no match

Tags: c++

```
if(response=='y'){
    cout << "great. file saved, please send the file to me and you'll receive the package information and status.";
}
else if(response=='n'){
    cout << "exiting. please do it again correctly, thanks!";
}
```

The above code gives me the following compile error:

> error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::string {aka
>   std::basic_string}' and 'char')|

I don't know what the issue is.

Could anyone give some advice on this? Thanks!

Comment: Use `"y"` rather than `'y'`.

Answer (score 3):

`'y'` is a character literal, and there is no conversion operator comparing `std::string` with a character.  There is an operator for comparing to other `std::string` objects, or to C-style strings, so using `"y"` and `"n"` instead will work.

Comment: its taking a y or a n (yes or a no) from the user by cin tho?

Comment: @exceem `'y'` and `"y"` are not the same thing.

Comment: @exceem `std::cin` returns a string, and it returns whatever the user types, not just `"y"` or `"n". It will store the entire string of characters it sees until it runs into whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

`'n'` is a `char`, `response` is a string. Strings are arrays of characters. I don't know how you're assigning a value to `response`, but if you're pulling from an istream, you're going to have to sanitize it before you can use it. You will then either have to use either

```
if(response=="y") //note the double quotes
```

to compare the entire string to a string of length 1

or

```
if(response[0]=='y')
```

to compare one character in the string.

Comment: what does the [0] do?

Comment: `response[n]` gets the n-th `char` from the string. Index 0 ist the first `char`.